# map on android device showing only one marker from url but showing all the values when I use Toast

Tags: android, json, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I have tried many changes researching on google but my problem isn't resolved. I have an URL which contains following data. On map it should show **more than one marker** as I have 9 coordinates. But it is showing one marker with coordinates of last values of response. Any help can be appreciated.

```
{  
   "status":200,
   "response":[  
      {  
     "docId":"1",
     "docName":"Madan",
     "docMobileNumber":"9676499774",
     "location":"S R Nagar",
     "specialization":"ENT",
     "avaliablity":"Available",
     "lat":"17.4436",
     "log":"78.4458"
      },
      {  
     "docId":"2",
     "docName":"Kumar",
     "docMobileNumber":"9052598855",
     "location":"KPHB",
     "specialization":"Pediatrician",
     "avaliablity":"Available",
     "lat":"17.4948",
     "log":"78.3996"
      },
      {  
     "docId":"3",
     "docName":"charan",
     "docMobileNumber":"8080809089",
     "location":"Ameerpet",
     "specialization":"Dentist",
     "avaliablity":"Available",
     "lat":"17.4375",
     "log":"78.4483"
      },
      {  
     "docId":"4",
     "docName":"Vamsy",
     "docMobileNumber":"7777778888",
     "location":"Kukatpally",
     "specialization":"Orthopedic",
     "avaliablity":"Available",
     "lat":"17.4948",
     "log":"78.3996"
      },
      {  
     "docId":"5",
     "docName":"Ganesh",
     "docMobileNumber":"9878686544",
     "location":"Dilsuk Nagar",
     "specialization":"Dermatologist",
     "avaliablity":"Available",
     "lat":"17.3688",
     "log":"78.5247"
      },
      {  
     "docId":"6",
     "docName":"Savitri",
     "docMobileNumber":"8786599452",
     "location":" West Marredpally",
     "specialization":"Physician",
     "avaliablity":"Not Available",
     "lat":"17.4500",
     "log":"78.5006"
      },
      {  
     "docId":"7",
     "docName":"Sandhya",
     "docMobileNumber":"9873243687",
     "location":"Bowenpally",
     "specialization":"Eye Specialist",
     "avaliablity":"Available",
     "lat":"17.898",
     "log":"78.5008"
      },
      {  
     "docId":"8",
     "docName":"Padma",
     "docMobileNumber":"9768832418",
     "location":"Kompally",
     "specialization":"Cardiologist",
     "avaliablity":"Not Available",
     "lat":"17.5600",
     "log":"78.5343"
      },
      {  
     "docId":"9",
     "docName":"Priya",
     "docMobileNumber":"9898767654",
     "location":"Tirumalgiri",
     "specialization":"Nerphrologist",
     "avaliablity":"Available",
     "lat":"17.787",
     "log":"78.9805"
      }
   ]
}
```

```
package com.example.charan.markermap;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Maps3 extends FragmentActivity {

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, Double>> locationList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Double>>();
    JSONArray locations = new JSONArray();
    int json1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

        new TaskRead().execute();
    }


    public class TaskRead extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> implements OnMapReadyCallback {

        ProgressDialog pg;
        Double latitude, longitude;

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
            mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
            pg = ProgressDialog.show(Maps3.this, "Please Wait", "Conecting to Server");
            pg.setCancelable(true);
        }


        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {

                String url = "http://192.168.1.33:8282/DocFinderServices/doctorService/doctorsList";

                HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);
                HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpget);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                InputStream inputStreamResponse = entity.getContent();

                String str = convertStreamToString(inputStreamResponse);

                if (str != null) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(str);

                        // Getting JSON Array node
                        locations = jsonObj.getJSONArray("response");
                        json1 = jsonObj.getInt("status");

                        // looping through All records
                        for (int i = 0; i < locations.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject c = locations.getJSONObject(i);

                            latitude = c.getDouble("lat");
                            longitude = c.getDouble("log");

                            // tmp hashmap for single contact
                            HashMap<String, Double> location = new HashMap<>();

                            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                            location.put("latitude", latitude);
                            location.put("longitude", longitude);
                            locationList.add(location);
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } else {
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Void gmap) {
            mMap.clear();
            Marker[] allMarkers = new Marker[locationList.size()];
            Toast.makeText(Maps3.this, "The list size is " + locationList.size(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            for (int i = 0; i < locationList.size(); i++) {

                if (mMap != null && json1 == 200) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < locationList.size(); j++) {
                        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
                        allMarkers[i] = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                .position(latLng)
                                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ok)));
                        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 14.0f));
                        mMap.getUiSettings().isZoomGesturesEnabled();
                    }

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(Maps3.this, "Oops..their is no map........", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
            pg.dismiss();

        }

        public String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            try {
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                    reader.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            return sb.toString();
        }

        @Override
        public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
            mMap = googleMap;

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just changed `LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);` to new values of getting key pair values as
 `LatLng latLng = new LatLng(Double.valueOf(locationList.get(j).get("latitude")), Double.valueOf(locationList.get(j).get("longitude")));`. Now it is working.

Answer (score 2):

Try with execute `TaskRead` after you got callback `onMapReady()`.

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

// Set Zoom Controls and Gestures on map
    mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true)
    mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomGesturesEnabled(true)

    new TaskRead().execute();    
}
```

Implements `OnMapReadyCallback` inside `FragmentActivity` and initialize your `SupportMapFragment` in `onCreate` method like below.

```
public class Maps3 extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

}
```

Try to set zoom Controls and Gestures on map and try with zoom in or zoom out and see, is there other marker added on map or not ?

Check my updated `onMapReady` method.

Comment: I have changed my code as your suggestion. Again it is showing only one marker instead of showing all 10 markers at a time which are available in url. Thank you

Comment: I have changed my code as your update. But again same problem. I think I have to use adapter. But I am unaware using adapters in map for markers. Please help.